# Merging an outdated branch with HEAD in CVS (Eclipse)

Tags: java, merge, cvs, branching-and-merging

Basically, we have a branch (call it B, it contains some branch specific code) which needs to be merged with HEAD. The problem we're having is that the branch was created long time ago. Since then, HEAD has been updated many times with lots of new features and many bugs have been fixed. The B branch still has most of the bugs already fixed in HEAD and it lacks some features. So, what needs doing is to take some features of branch B (there are probably about 50 files that contain new functionality - I don't know exactly what these files are) while leaving the rest of HEAD intact.

Currently, the merge tool in Eclipse reports more than 1700 changes, doing automatic merge overwrites code in HEAD with that from the branch (thus, introducing back bugs that have already been fixed). Is there a better way to tackle this instead of going through all the 1700 changes and manually merging them?

Comment: Did you tag the base of the branch?

Comment: TIL people still use CVS. Personally, I'd recommend converting the whole thing to Subversion and then attempting this, but there's probably a specific reason driving the continued use of CVS, no?

Comment: @parsifal: Yes, I believe there is a starting tag.

Comment: @Alan Krueger: It's kind of a legacy project and I'm afraid there is no chance we can stop using CVS.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you want to find out what's changed on the specific branch, and apply those changes to trunk. I think the simplest way to do this is to create a patchfile.

Start by checking out the base and tip of the branch into separate directories. You said that you have a base tag, which puts you ahead of 99% of the people who use CVS. If that's not the case, then you can do a date-based checkout. Finding the correct date will be a pain; the easiest way will be to look at the log for a file that you know wasn't changed on the branch, and track down where that branch appears in the revision history.

Second step is to create a patch file that describes all the changes made on the branch. The instructions [here](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/163/how-to-create-patch-file-using-patch-and-diff/) seem complete (I did a Google search for "create a patchile" and looked at the top results).

What you do next depends on how big the patch is, and how much the trunk has changed since the branch was cut. If you feel lucky, the easiest way is to check out the trunk and apply the patch as described in the linked document. You're likely to get at least a few failures, and you need to check each of the changes anyway to verify that it still makes sense.

The alternative is to have three windows open: Window #1 is the patchfile, which will tell you the files that changed and what changed in them. Window #2 is the file on the (tip of) the branch, so you can see what it's currently doing. Window #3 is the file on your trunk. In this approach, you copy code from #2 to #3 where it makes sense, and #1 is just used as a guide to what gets copied.

For what it's worth, while CVS is particularly painful at branching and merging, no VCS is good at merging highly-diverged branches (no matter what Joel says).